# Flutter firebase adding new data

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a button which is create a new data for firebase.
But when i change the data its updating , but i want to add a new one.
For example , this is my set part;

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
    _firestore.collection("UsersTodos").doc(username).set({
      'userTodo': [_todoController.text],
    });
  },
  icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
```

When i enter another value to textfield my document is updating and change the value, i need to create an another value for that document.

[image]

Shall i loop this area with for loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, it should add items to list:

```
_firestore.collection("UsersTodos").doc(username).update({
    'userTodo': FieldValue.arrayUnion([_todoController.text]),
});
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. But there is a problem. My data comes like [first,second,third] i want to seperate them. When i get them like listofDocumentSnap[index]['userTodo'] it is not coming 1 by 1 . Its comming like array i want to seperate them

Comment: I think this method won't work. I need to convert this like userTodo0 , userTodo1,userTodo2